# TS2536:Type 'keyof T2' cannot be used to index type 'T1'

Tags: typescript

The swagger-api/swagger-codegen generates following code:

```
private extendObj<T1,T2>(objA: T1, objB: T2) {
    for(let key in objB){
        if(objB.hasOwnProperty(key)){
            objA[key] = objB[key];
        }
    }
    return <T1&T2>objA;
}
```

which yields the error when compiling:

TS2536:Type 'keyof T2' cannot be used to index type 'T1'

Could somebody please explain why one object's key can't be used to access another's object fiel? Is the key inferred to some special type?

And what would be the correct way to copy object's properties in typescript?

Comment: If there's no guarantee that the keys are of the same type, I can see the compiler having an issue with that. What happens if you specify the type of `key` as something generic?

Comment: it works, if another keyX is declared out of the cycle. But it's weird. I'd undertand if it complained about value, but it's key.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the correct function should look [like this](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=%20function%20extendObj%3CT1%2CT2%3E(objA%3A%20T1%7CT2%2C%20objB%3A%20T2)%3A%20T1%7CT2%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20for(let%20key%20in%20objB)%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20if(objB.hasOwnProperty(key))%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20objA%5Bkey%5D%20%3D%20objB%5Bkey%5D%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20objA%3B%0D%0A%7D):

```
function extendObj<T1,T2>(objA: T1|T2, objB: T2): T1|T2 {
    for(let key in objB){
        if(objB.hasOwnProperty(key)){
            objA[key] = objB[key];
        }
    }
    return objA;
}
```

The returned type should be the union of `T1` and `T2` (`|`) not the intersection (`&`).

Perhaps you're not familiar with `keyof` it's a new feature in [TypeScript 2.1](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-1.html).

I suppose the reasoning of the compiler is that it knows that `key` is a valid member of `T2` but it doesn't know about `T1` that's why I say that `objA` is a union of `T1` and `T2` (it isn't really but I want to assign to the `keyof T2` fields). The compiler isn't differentiating between reads and writes.

I'm not familiar with swagger-codegen, do you have any control on, or can you edit, the generated code?

Comment: yes, you're right I didn't read about keyof attentively enough. Now I got it. Although the code you've suggested sitll doesn't compile. This one does though: extendObj<T1,T2 extends T1>(objA:T2, objB: T2): T1|T2 {
            for(let key in objB){
                if(objB.hasOwnProperty(key)){
                    objA[key] = objB[key];
                }
            }
            return objA;

Comment: My code compiled on the typescript playground (see my link)

Comment: and T2 extends T1 looks much nicer to my java eye than T1|T2 :)

Comment: hmm, getting 'error TS2536: Type 'keyof T2' cannot be used to index type 'T1 | T2'.' from typescript@2.1.4. Different versions?

Comment: @user656449 `extends` has different semantics than `|`. Have a look at the tinyurl "extend-with-extends" (SO won't let me put the link here and the full link is too long to enter in a comment)

Answer (score 4):

I've fixed it by casting with intersection type <T1 & T2>. https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html

```typescript
/** Extends objA with properties of objB and returns objA */
function extendObj<T1, T2>(objA: T1, objB: T2): T1 & T2 {
    for (let key in objB) {
        if (objB.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            (<T1 & T2>objA)[key] = (<T1 & T2>objB)[key];
        }
    }
    return <T1 & T2>objA;
}

/** Creates an object with the specified prototype and properties coming from object (cloned) */
function fromPrototype<T, A>(prototype: T, object: A): T & A {
    // Create the object with the specified prototype
    const newObject = <T & A>Object.create(prototype);

    // Clones properties of the specified object
    for (const prop in object) {
        if (object.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
            newObject[prop] = (<T & A>object)[prop];
        }
    }

    return newObject;
}
```